# Why does getting the base address using GetModuleHandle work?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
DWORD baseAddress = (DWORD) GetModuleHandle(NULL);
```

If I put that code into a DLL and inject it to a process, that seems to equal the base address of the injected process.

How does that work exactly? How does the cast from HMODULE to DWORD work? Would it work if I cast it to void* instead of DWORD?

Comment: On a 64 bit machine this won't work because `DWORD` is 32 bits. But a `HMODULE` is just a `void *` pointer anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an implementation detail of the 32-bit and 64-bit version of Windows.  HMODULE is older than that, in the 16-bit version of Windows they were true handles.  That was not necessary anymore in win32, the virtual memory address at which a module is loaded uniquely identifies the module.  So using the VM address was preferable, no need to keep it in a handle table.

This does mean that you can't cast to DWORD, not good enough to store a virtual memory address on the 64-bit version.  You'll need to use DWORD_PTR.

Answer (score 3):

It works because Windows just happened to use the base address as an identifying handle, and because on a 32-bit system an address fits into a DWORD. Since Windows isn't required to do that, you shouldn't rely on it for anything.