# 64 bit equivalent of "GetModuleHandleA" need

Tags: c++, winapi, process, pid, ida

I need to extent the compatibility of my application to 64 bit exe.

```
__int64 GetGameFunctionAddress(std::string GameFileExe, std::string Address)
  {
    // Get integer value address of the original function hook

    #if defined(_WIN64)

        /// code to emulate GetModuleHandleA on 64 executible

    #else

        return (__int64)GetModuleHandleA(GameFileExe.c_str()) + std::strtoul(Address.c_str(), NULL, 16);
    
    #end if
    
}
```

this function get Address to pass to IDA for hook a function of a game.

I call this function with this line:

```
Output.MainFunctHookAddressInt = GetGameFunctionAddress(Output.ExeFile, GameInfo.MainFunctHookAddressInt);

AddressOfHookSoundFunction = Output.MainFunctHookAddressInt;
```

and in a second time I pass it to detours:

```
DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHookSoundFunction, HookMainFunction);
```

Unfortunately "GetModuleHandleA" work only on 32 bit games, but I need to extend the compatibility to 64 bit games too.

So I need to fix my 'GetGameFunctionAddress' function to add 64 bit compatibility.

Can you help me please ?

**Update:**

One user tell me:

According to this GetModuleHandleA does not work to get the base address if the process is 64bit.
[Why does getting the base address using GetModuleHandle work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066847/why-does-getting-the-base-address-using-getmodulehandle-work)

Comment: `GetModuleHandle` of course work in both 64bit and 32bit. unclear about what you ask

Comment: @RbMm afaik there are issues if your app and another app are in different realms.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie - `GetModuleHandleA` say that all happens in the same process

Comment: One user tell me:  According to this GetModuleHandleA does not work to get the base address if the process is 64bit.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066847/why-does-getting-the-base-address-using-getmodulehandle-work

Comment: The answer says: Do not truncate your (potentially 64-bit wide) address to a 32-bit wide `DWORD`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GetModuleHandleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlew) returns a value of type `HMODULE` (which is [the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) as `HINSTANCE`, aka `HANDLE`, aka `PVOID`, aka `void*`). In other words: It returns a pointer sized value.

Pointer sized values are 32 bits wide in 32-bit processes, and 64 bits wide in 64-bit processes. Either way you get the address of the module base address, irrespective of the bitness of the process.

Now obviously, since you are interacting with filesystem objects that aren't under your control, you do **not** want to call the ANSI version of the API (`GetModuleHandleA`) but the Unicode version: `GetModuleHandleW`. And while you're doing pretty low-level stuff here, you probably don't want to use types from the C++ Standard Library either (if you insist, use `std::wstring`/`std::wstring_view`).

Comment: In short you suggest to use "GetModuleHandleW" and "std::wstring" on both cases ?

Comment: Yes, and no. Always use `GetModuleHandleW`, yes, regardless of target architecture. No, don't use `std::wstring` at all. Presumably, you're infiltrating a foreign process. You should not assume that the C++ support libraries are fully initialized, or that the target process is even using them. Keep things as C-like as possible (pick Rust for a C-replacement with bonuses).

Comment: Thank you ! I will try and let you known !